# Serialization of R object via RinRuby

Tags: r, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Rails` app which uses `R` on server side for some computations. The process is as follows:

1. Get user details
2. initialize an R object using `RinRuby`
3. do some calculations inside the `R` object (i.e sample 2 items from a pool)
4. pass data from object to user
5. get user's response (i.e the id of chosen item), pass it to `R` object
6. back to step 3 until max number of steps reached.

Now, it was all nice and well when I have performed my unit tests, because it was always the same `ruby` instance with the same `R` connection. When we moved into testing the controllers, things went bad. Why? because each request results in a new `R` connection, menaing a new `R` object is created. Regarding the steps mentioned before - The `R` object in step 5 is not the same one from step s 2-3, which means the items sampled in step 3 (and then passed to the user) are not the ones sampled when getting the object in step 5, this of course results with an error for illegal input.

Any ideas on how to store the `R` object conveniently and efficiently? This system is supposed to serve thousands of clients simultaneously, so keeping all `R` connections open is a bad idea.

PS the `R` object itself is quite heavy, so serialization using `serialize` and then pulling it using `as.character` is infeasible :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RinRuby (so pls take this answer with a grain of salt), but took a look at its source code and it seems it is just a relatively thin wrapper around spawning R in a separate process and piping input/output.

So, in fact, you don't have an R object in your Ruby app (the one referenced via `R` is just a wrapper itself - it doesn't contain an R state but just pipes commands/results back and forth and does some "housekeeping").

So if you need access to the same R object/state between requests to your Rails app you will need some additional boilerplate. For example, `R.eval` seems to allow sending arbitrary R commands to R process, so if R supports saving/loading the state this might work.

But if the state is large and you have multiple steps that should work with this state evolving, several save/load might be a pain and something more sophisticated might be necessary. For example, a separate Ruby server that will keep connections to R processes open while your main Rails app needs them (might be tricky to implement reliably though)...

Anyway, the point is that your question is not about the serialization of R state within Rails app - because your Rails app doesn't have direct access to this state. Some additional design efforts seems to be necessary here.